# Как ограничить создание экземпляров класса?(не больше 5 экземпляров класса)

Tags: python, ооп

Хочу создать класс в котором можно определить только 5 экземпляров класса, через метод **new**

```
class Dog:

    __count = 0

    def __new__(cls, *args,**kwargs):
        if Dog.__count<5:
            cls.self.__name = super(Dog, cls).__new__(cls)
        else:
            print('Не больше пяти собак!')

    def __init__(self):
        Dog.__count += 1
```

Comment: Ну, хотите. А что за код? В чём проблема?

Comment: Код через который я пытаюсь это сделать, и он не работает

Comment: Как именно он не работает?

Comment: По задумке нужно что бы при создании экземпляра класса проверялось не больше ли 5 экземпляров уже, если больше то, выводилось надпись что нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def __new__(cls, *args,**kwargs):

    if Dog.__count<5:
        obj = super(Dog, cls).__new__(cls)
        return obj
    else:
        print('Не больше пяти собак!')
```

Справка по [__ new__()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__).

Comment: Спасибо,сработало.